# JPanel "<identifier> expected" error message

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I created my very basic window for game but in `JPanel` I have this error

```
<identifier> expected.
```

I trying to fix it but I can't.

```
package gui;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.PopupMenu;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Frame
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int FWIDTH = 780;
        int FHEIGHT = 520;

        //The frame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(FWIDTH, FHEIGHT));
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(new Color(69, 99, 4@));
    }
}
```

Waiting for help!

Comment: Read each line in turn and determine why this `frame.getContentPane().add(panel);` is wrong...You might also like to take a look at [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) and [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)

Comment: Tell us the complete error.

Comment: what is expected? please give us all of the error you have got.

Answer (score 0):

```
frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
                           ↑ 
                           ?
```

You can use a variable only *after* it was *declared*.

I highly recommend you to go through a [basic Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial) and then read about [Java Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/).

Answer (score 0):

I tried to modify your code to get your colored window out there please be aware that you made a mistake to define the background color: change 4@ to 40.

The other change I made is defining Panel object first.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.PopupMenu;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Frame
{

    //The frame


    public static void main(String arg[]){
        int FWIDTH = 780;
        int FHEIGHT = 520;

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(FWIDTH, FHEIGHT));
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


        panel.setBackground(new Color(69, 99, 40));


    }
}
```